# Entity Framework 4.3 Modify T4 Template for generating classes

Tags: poco, t4, database-migration, composite-key, entity-framework-4.3

I have a database-first model generated with full primary keys. Database first model works fine. However now I have upgraded my Entity Framework 4.3. I have modified the standard T4 template that comes with EF.

Now when I use Add-Migration initial to the project it is complaining that my entities do not have the Primary keys defined. Which is not true (or to some extent)... looking deeper I have composite keys for which EF expects me to define `[Key, Column(0)]` on all of the key elements.

```
System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'SupplierWarehouses' is based on type 'SupplierWarehouses' that has no keys defined.
```

The problem I am facing is I trying to modify the `WriteProperty` method of T4 Template (DbContext) and there seems to be no `Entity Key` Property on `System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmProperty` object. Now this property is shown from Visual Studio Model Editor so Theory is it should exist.

Appreciate if some one could help me with this

Sanj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out `System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmProperty` does not have it this property, it needs to be referred from `System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityType` the actual property is `KeyMembers`.

I made the change to T4 `WriteProperty` to accept Entity Object now it works as beauty.